# Assembly 'Segmentation Fault' When Trying to Print Decimal Number

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to create a macro that will print a decimal number for me. My idea was to divide the number by ten, convert the remainder to ASCII and push it into the stack until the the ratio is 0. I then print the digits one by one but for some reason I get a 'Segmentation fault'.

I am using Linux, nasm, and a x86_64 processor.

```
%macro printInt 1
    mov rax, %1
    mov rbx, 0
%%loop1:                  ;Convert all digits to ascii
    inc rbx               ;Count of the digits in number
    mov rdx, 0
    div rax
    add rdx, 48           ;Convert remainder to ascii
    push rdx              ;Push remainder into stack
    cmp rax, 0            ;Compare ratio to 0
    jne %%loop1
%%loop2:                  ;Print the number digit by digit
    dec rbx

    mov rax, 1            ;Sys_Write
    mov rdi, 1            ;STDOUT
    pop rsi               ;Pop digit
    mov rdx, 1
    syscall

    cmp rbx, 0
    jne %%loop2
%endmacro

section .data
    number1 db 123

section .text
    global _start
_start:

    printInt number1

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ (this is hint "use debugger" to figure out, what is the reason for segfault) ... and second hint is: why macro? I don't see any reason to write this as macro instead of standard sub-routine (but I see many reasons why to not write it as macro, macros used like this makes debugging and code review lot more difficult)

Comment: I don't know how to use the gdu debugger and I used a macro because I guess it reminds me of functions. Can you reccommend a good debugger for me? I can't seem to install DDD or Insight for some reason

Comment: I use personally https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/ (compiled from sources, but I think recently some distros may have it already in repositories, try to search for "edb-debugger"). It is quite work-in-progress evolving a lot and so far I wouldn't recommend it for debugging of large projects, but just for learning basics of x86 assembly it should work very well, it has all basic tools. Macros are not functions, macros duplicate the instructions everywhere where you use it. Use proper functions, i.e. write the code once somewhere, and then `call` it from other code.

Comment: while learning basics of x86 assembly, you should have zero need/usage for macros, after all those are assembler directives, not something what makes it into final binary, so everything you can write with macro, you can write with pure assembly too and in the beginning all the stuff which may smell like "macro can save me lot of typing here" in reality means "I should restructure my assembly better". There are times at which macros can seriously help to keep source easier to read/maintain or more performant, but none of that should emerge while you are learning basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First mistake:**

```
number1 db 123
```

number1 is defined as BYTE, but will be treated as QUADWORD (`mov rax, %1`). Change it to

```
number1 dq 123
```

**Second mistake:**

```
printInt number1
```

The macro gets the argument as string. So, `mov rax, %1` will be solved to `mov rax, number1`. In NASM, `RAX` will get the address of `number1`, not the value. Change it to

```
printInt [number1]
```

**Third mistake:**

```
div rax
```

means: Divide RDX:RAX by RAX, store the result in RAX and the remainder in RDX. This will always result in RAX=1 and RDX=0. Use another register with the value 10.

**Fourth mistake:**

```
pop rsi
```

The SYSCALL/RAX=1 routine of the kernel expects a pointer in RSI, not a number. There are several ways to address the problem. I leave that to your imagination.